# Laravel Directory Restructuration

Tags: php, apache, laravel, frameworks, composer-php

I am very confused as to how to change Laravel's directory structure.

I changed my directory structure to go from this structure:

```
Source Files
  + app
  + bootstrap
  + public
```

to the following structure :

```
Source Files
  + app
    + public
  + bootstrap
```

In order to change the directory structure, I changed the path of `public` within `bootstrap/paths.php`, so it now looks like this `'public' => __DIR__.'/../app/public'`

After doing this, `app/public/index.php` was giving me an error saying that it couldn't find `autoload.php` or `start.php`, so I went inside the file and changed the path of both files to the following:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
```

Now the `localhost:8000` actually loads, but there is a problem - In order for the views to be able to load css/javascript files, they need to be in two directories simultaneously, `/public` and `/app/public`. If I remove a css file from `/public`, the view gets messed up. If I remove a css file from `/app/public`, the view gets messed up as well.

Here is an example of how I am loading a css file from the view, in this case, `layout.blade.php`:

```
<link href="css/core/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Can someone explain to me please what in the world is going on, and maybe a possible solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how your edits would affect the overall picture (I understand what you've done, but not having restructured the tree personally, I'm unaware of the implications)...

However, with that being said; I personally always utilize the laravel features to ensure the correct path is being used. For example, loading a css...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('/') . '/' }}css/default.css">
```

I hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: One thing to note about doing the above is that once this is changed, you can then open the page in a browser and check what laravel wrote for the directory and ensure the changes totally took and nothing is routing to the old directory structure.

Comment: {{{ URL::to('/')}}} returns the path to my root directory, which is localhost:8000/, since I want to go to localhost:8000/app/public, I used the following {{{ URL::to('/') . '/app/public/'}}}, but it still doesn't work :( My guess is that it's going to routes.php and then attempting to do the appropriate action?

Comment: Okay, disregard my last comment. {{{ URL::to('/')}}} has the same effect as not adding it at all. Removing a css/js file from either of the public directories messes it all up :(

Comment: Alright, so what exactly is happening when you remove the old css/js from the original public folder? Are you getting an error message or is it just not loading? I'd suggest checking your host logs to see if it's coming up 404 for the assets you're trying to load.
Also, are you using an application you've developed already or are you working with a fresh install of Laravel?

Comment: Hey Jerimiah! The only thing that happens is that the page isn't styled any more, and all the logic I implemented with javascript doesn't work any more. When I remove a css/javascript file from either of the public directories I have, I do get a 404 error on the css/javascript file. I am working on a fresh install of Laravel, all I did was move the css in the 'hello' view to its own css file, called hello.css to test for the issue I'm having.

Comment: Have you tried loading it (js or css) via direct access? (http://localhost:8000/js/nameoffile.js) Don't worry about the laravel configuration for now. What I'm thinking is perhaps something going on with your .htaccess file. Try to load the file with it only being in one folder, then the other. You can also check your .htaccess file and see if you find something similar to this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`